# Show nb-datepicker in ng-sidebar

Tags: angular, sass, angular6

I need to show nb-datepicker in ng-sidebar on Angular 6 based web portal. The main issue is that I am unable to change the CSS of ng-sidebar (z-index is 99999999 by default) and hence the popup for the datepicker hides behind the sidebar (z-index of date picker container is 1000).

I have tried changing/overriding the CSS directly. When I inspect elements, I can see the an 'aside' element in 'ng-sidebar'. The 'aside' element has the following CSS:

```
.ng-sidebar[_ngcontent-c17] {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: absolute;
    touch-action: auto;
    will-change: initial;
    z-index: 99999999;
}
```

Changing the 'z-index' to 999 brings the DatePicker to front but I am unable to apply this style from my component.scss file.

Need help with that. I have tried:

```
:host ::ng-deep aside{
      z-index: 999;
}
```

and

```
.ng-sidebar[_ngcontent-c17]{
      z-index: 999;
}
```

and many more combinations but nothing solved the problem. Please help.

Comment: I think that you only need give class to your ng-datepicker and, in css .yourclass{z-index:15000!important}

Answer (score 0):

Use ::ng-deep as

```
::ng-deep .ng-sidebar[_ngcontent-c17] {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: absolute;
    touch-action: auto;
    will-change: initial;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. Somehow, it was always getting overriden.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code on your CSS or CSS file

```
 ng-sidebar-container {
    z-index: 100;
 }
```